# access facebooks api info in multiple return variable

Tags: jquery, facebook-javascript-sdk

I would like to get facebook's api values and return multiple variables so that i can use it on several different pages on my site. 
This is what i would like to do, but since FB is `async` the values are delayed.

How would i be able to get those values when they are ready?

```
function getFBinfo(){
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            FB.Canvas.getPageInfo(
                    function(info) {

                            var myClientHeight = info.clientHeight;
                            var myClientWidth = info.clientWidth;
                            var myOffsetLeft = info.offsetLeft;

                            return {clientHeight:myClientHeight, clientWidth:myClientWidth, offsetLeft:myOffsetLeft };
                    }
            ); 

        }
    });
}
```

then access the variables on some page like:

```
en  var n = getFBinfo(); 
console.log(n.clientHeight);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As facebook getPageInfo method is async method, so you can pass callback instead of returning value, try this,

```
function getFBinfo(callback){
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        FB.Canvas.getPageInfo(
                function(info) {

                        var myClientHeight = info.clientHeight;
                        var myClientWidth = info.clientWidth;
                        var myOffsetLeft = info.offsetLeft;
                        callback({clientHeight:myClientHeight,     clientWidth:myClientWidth, offsetLeft:myOffsetLeft });
                }
        ); 

    }
  });
}

function mycallback(obj)
{
     //You can handle output here
     console.log(obj.clientHeight);
 }

 var n = getFBinfo(mycallback);
```